# How to plot Ocean Currents with Cartopy

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy, netcdf4

I am trying to plot a netCDF4 file containing ocean currents from a NASA database for a project, but I keep getting errors such as "x and y coordinates are not compatible with the shape of the vector components".

I have tried changing the streamplot to a contourf (when I did it said that it needed to be a 2d array) which I tried to change but I could not get it to work.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset as netcdf_dataset
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fname = "oscar_vel2019.nc.gz.nc"

data=netcdf_dataset(fname)
v = data.variables['v'][0, :, :, :]
vf = data.variables['vm'][0, :, :, :]
u = data.variables['u'][0, :, :, :]
uf = data.variables['um'][0, :, :, :]
lats = data.variables['latitude'][:]
lons = data.variables['longitude'][:]
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

mymap=plt.streamplot(lons, lats, u, v, 60, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.coastlines()

plt.show()
```

I would like it to work such that the ocean currents are visible on the plot and to show the movement of particles in the currents through an animation. I really don't have much knowledge with this which is why I am asking. Here is the link from which I got the file: https://podaac-opendap.jpl.nasa.gov/opendap/hyrax/allData/oscar/preview/L4/oscar_third_deg/oscar_vel2019.nc.gz.html

Comment: If lat  and Lon are 1-d variables you need to use mesh grid to make same size as u and v

Comment: I am sorry if I am asking a stupid question, but I have not done anything like this before so I am not sure how mesh grid would work. So, do you mind showing an example as to how I would do that? I tried doing that earlier as such;
x, y = np.meshgrid(u, v)
mymap=plt.streamplot(lons, lats, x, y, 60, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

but this just gave me a memory error: MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (577681, 577681) and data type float64

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html

Comment: You should meshgrid lat and Lon not u and v if lat and Lon are 1d variables.   If they are already two d then that won’t help of course.

Comment: I tried using a reduced dataset instead, but although the memory error no longer comes, now I get this error; ValueError: x and y coordinates are not compatible with the shape of the vector components. Could someone help me out with what this would indicate and what I need to change?

Comment: You need to tell us the dimensions of the data or it’s hard to know what’s going wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I downloaded the data.  The problem is that u and v are 4-dimensional, so you need to squeeze out the "depth" dimension.  Cartopy also doesn't accept longitudes greater than 180, and you probably won't get away with stream plotting the whole thing.  Also, density=60 will take forever...

This is ugly, but gives you the idea.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with xr.open_dataset('/Users/jklymak/downloads/oscar_vel2019.nc.gz.nc') as ds:
    print(ds)

    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    dec = 10
    lon = ds.longitude.values[::dec]
    lon[lon>180] = lon[lon>180] - 360
    mymap=plt.streamplot(lon, ds.latitude.values[::dec], ds.u.values[0, 0, ::dec, ::dec], ds.v.values[0, 0, ::dec, ::dec], 6, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.coastlines()
    plt.show()
```

[image]